# how to create list view into fragment

Tags: android

i have a slidinglayout that contain 4 fragment , one of these fragment should use a listview in side but when i run my app its crash ,, so here my code .

the news.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this my news.java

```
public class News extends Fragment {
    ListView myListView;
    String[] news={"first","Secound","Third"}; 
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){

        View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.news, container, false);
        myListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, news);
        myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;
    }
```

and here is the slidinglayout fragment manager

```
class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{



    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Fragment fragment=null;
        if(position==0){
            fragment=new Generalization();

        }
        if(position==1){
            fragment=new Report();

        }
        if(position==2){
            fragment=new Templet();

        }
        if(position==3){
            fragment=new News();

        }
        return fragment;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 4;
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        String title="";
        if(position==0){
            title="     تعميم     ";
        }
        if(position==1){
            title="     نماذج     ";
        }
        if(position==2){
            title="     تقارير     ";
        }
        if(position==3){
            title="     أخبار     ";
        }
        return title;

    }

}
```

please tell me where is the error ,,

here is the logcat ,,

```
02-05 12:38:24.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at com.uigtc.kasd.SlidingTabLayout$TabClickListener.onClick(SlidingTabLayout.java:315)
02-05 12:38:24.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
02-05 12:38:24.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
02-05 12:38:24.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-05 12:38:24.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-05 12:38:24.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-05 12:38:24.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
02-05 12:38:24.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 12:38:24.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-05 12:38:24.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
02-05 12:38:24.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
02-05 12:38:24.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-05 12:38:26.353: D/dalvikvm(1532): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 61K, 4% free 3772K/3928K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
02-05 12:38:26.353: I/dalvikvm-heap(1532): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.376MB for 637572-byte allocation
02-05 12:38:26.389: D/dalvikvm(1532): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 4392K/4552K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
02-05 12:38:26.413: D/dalvikvm(1532): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 3% free 4853K/4992K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
02-05 12:38:26.421: D/dalvikvm(1532): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 3% free 4921K/5056K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
02-05 12:38:26.429: I/dalvikvm-heap(1532): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.890MB for 4194316-byte allocation
02-05 12:38:26.437: D/dalvikvm(1532): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 9017K/9156K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
02-05 12:38:26.549: D/libEGL(1532): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
02-05 12:38:26.553: D/(1532): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb860fbf8, tid 1532
02-05 12:38:26.573: D/libEGL(1532): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
02-05 12:38:26.577: D/libEGL(1532): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
02-05 12:38:26.621: W/EGL_genymotion(1532): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-05 12:38:26.625: E/OpenGLRenderer(1532): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
02-05 12:38:26.625: E/OpenGLRenderer(1532): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
02-05 12:38:26.637: E/OpenGLRenderer(1532): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
02-05 12:38:26.641: E/OpenGLRenderer(1532): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
02-05 12:38:26.641: D/OpenGLRenderer(1532): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: where is your logcat?

Comment: take a look at [what is logcat?](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html)

Comment: oooh yes i know this thing but i didnt use it i dont know why ,,, i am sorry

Comment: when crash comes, open logCat and copy whatever comes there and post it here.

Answer (score 3):

When you are using fragments in your android applications you can't populate the widget data inside it in the onCreateView method because the View hasn't been placed on the screen yet(it needs to be returned).
So in fragment life cycle you first place the layout with the onCreateView and then populate the widgets in the onCreate method

So the solution is to make your onCreateView look like this:

```
public class News extends Fragment {
ListView myListView;
String[] news={"first","Secound","Third"}; 
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.news , container , false);
}
```

and populate the ListView data inside the onCreate function of the fragment.
In order to use the View , you just need to call

```
getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);....
```

Good Luck

Comment: Can you give the logcat?

Comment: can you help me with that ,, please explain more or check my code if its correct.

Comment: I already checked your code , i wanna know what your logcat is. If i would have it i probably could solve your problem...

Comment: First of all , if you look closely you will see the error with the onClick with your swipeable tabs...
Debug your code on the moment you handle your click on the tabs

Comment: if i delete this line of code **myListView.setAdapter(adapter);** its work without crash

Answer (score 0):

You might be having trouble with "getActivity" which sometimes returns "null". Try to store the reference to activity at "onAttach" method, then use it to create your adapter:

```
Activity activity

@Override
void onAttach (Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ...
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, news);
    myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps